# Ankor scrolling with easing

Tags: jquery, easing, jquery-easing

i use the libary easing to scroll to ankor, but my code doesnt work if i klick on a second ankor it jumps to top again and then dont work at all.
here is my homepage im working on:

http://www.o-hoerr.de

here is the jq i use:

```
$(function() {

//catch all the clicks on tags
$("a").click(function() {

//check if it has a #
if(this.hash){
//get rid of the # sign
var hash = this.hash.substr(1);

//get the position of the <a name>
var $toElement = $("a[name="+hash+"]");
var toPosition = $toElement.position().top;

//scroll/animate

$("body,html").animate({
  scrollTop : toPosition
},2000,"easeOutExpo");


return false;  
}



});

  if(location.hash) {
  var hash = location.hash;
  window.scroll(0,0);
  $("a[href="+hash+"]").click();

}


});
```

would be nice if someone could help me
sincerely Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting something (text) or a non-breaking-space in your Name-tag

e.g.:

```
<a name="Simulight">SSS</a>
<a name="Simulight">&nbsp</a>
```

Comment: nice it worked. i took the a tags out of the sliders. thanks. can anyone give me a hint how to improve performance?

Comment: Start a new thread and explain what performance you will improve. Thanks for voting me up

Comment: ok thanks. i cannot vote u up mate :( it says i need 15 reputation :(